# login into the site with my javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

i'm trying to login into the site with the following javascript. But, i'm loading only the complete page. I'm developing windows 8 app

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        // TODO: Initialize the page here.
        document.getElementById("bt_login").addEventListener("click", login, false);
    }
   });
  })();

function login() {
var xhrDiv = document.getElementById("xhrReport");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.onreadystatechange = dataLoaded;

xhr.open("POST", "http://www.160by2.com", true, <username>, <password>);
xhr.send();

function dataLoaded() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // OK
            xhrDiv.innerHTML = window.toStaticHTML("response:" + xhr.responseText);

        } else {
            // not OK
            xhrDiv.innerText = "failure";
        }
    }
};}
```

I want to dsiplay in `xhrdiv.innerHTML` as "LOGIN SUCCESS" or "LOGIN ERROR"

EDIT:

I tried the following code:

`iframe = document.getElementById("ifra_op");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.160by2.com/index");
        document.getElementById("op").appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("MobileNoLogin") = "<mobno>";
        iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("LoginPassword") = "<pass>;
        iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("LoginForm").click();`

But, there is an error. It says "Javascript run time error:math is undefined"

"math" comes from the website. I don't know how to handle this. Also, the permission is denied. Why is that so?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a service (something like a web service) in the remote server to process the request.

In here what you can do is.

1. Create an iframe and set the src to 160by2;
2. Access the webpage using iframe.contentwindow, inject your code to fill up the forms and trigger the submit button.
3. Parse the received html to verify your login.

**Use jquery , makes life easier.**

```
var iframe = $("#ifra_op");
$(iframe).attr("src", "http://www.160by2.com/index");
$(iframe).attr("onload","submitForm();");
function submitForm(){
$(iframe.contentWindow.document).find("#MobileNoLogin").val("9999"); 
$(iframe.contentWindow.document).find("#LoginPassword").val("pass"); 
$('#button').click();
}
```

Comment: hey. It says access is denied ;(

Comment: Can give me more details, like a screenshot or something